# Windows 8: SQL Server Connection Delay

Tags: sql-server, windows-8

I have just moved to Windows 8 on my dev box, and I am having an issue with all external `SqlConnection.Open()` commands taking 2+ seconds (connecting to local has no overhead). This is irrelevant of the SQL Server version (2005, 2008, or 2012) and no other network issues exist. I have tried a number of possible solutions (re-installing .net, SQL Server, Visual Studio, etc). What diagnosis tools are available to chase this down or what ideas does the community have?

PS - All `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`, `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`, etc calls also *had* a .5 second overhead. I was able to resolve that by adding `Encrypt = true` and `TrustServerCertificate = true` to the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: how are you connecting to the sql server, windows auth or sql login/password?

Comment: I have tried both methods with equal delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did use the Event Tracing for Windows, and there was nothing that jumped out at me. I also used dotTrace, again, nothing.

Eventually, a coworker who was using PerfMon noticed that the log was being spammed with Trend Micro notifications. In an attempt to dampen the noise, he stopped the service (using the SA tool), and the performance issue went away. It turns out that Trend Micro on windows 8 & windows server 2012 negatively affect SQL Server connections. Also, it is quite insidious and did not show up as a culprit in any logging or profiling tools. Yuck.

Answer (score 0):

The Sql server network libraries have extensive tracing available that ties into the ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) framework.  By using this tracing functionality, you'll be able to identify which portion of the connection is causing the 2 sec delay.

**Event Tracing for Windows**

The ETW framework is a very light weight, very fast event logging system that can capture ten's of thousands events per second with minimal overhead.  It's built into the windows core and consists of "providers" which publish events.  For example, IE, the sql client library, the .net framework and most windows system drivers expose events.

Subscribers register for the events they are interested in and that's it.  If no one is listening for an event, it turns into a minimal overhead no-op.  FYI, ETW drives the event logs for all versions starting with windows vista (when they introduced all the extra windows event logs beyond application, security and system)

**Data Access Tracing in the Sql Client Libraries**

Bob Beauchemin of http://www.sqlskills.com wrote an [excellent paper on the topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765421%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)  which is available on msdn. Go read it and do some googling for "ETW tracing", "BID tracing Sql client", etc.  Unfortunately it takes a bit of work to wrap your head around, but it is extremely powerful.

The process will be fairly straight forward.  Configure the trace, capture activity, stop and review the trace.  It will have detailed timing and you can capture stack traces as well, so you should be able to see the delay clearly and investigate it further. You can also mix in events for dns lookups, encryption, active directory access, network activity, etc, so if you reach a dead end try adding related events.  It will be an iterative process, and you'll probably end up learning more about the internals of System.Data.SqlClient then you'd prefer to.

Good luck, and if you need additional help making sense of the trace files then update your question and we'll work through it.